# When should questions on other sites be migrated here?

Tags: discussion

For example, I found [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48834/applying-a-multi-qubit-quantum-gate-to-specific-qubits) about how to apply gates to non-adjacent qubits, which is currently in the "Computer Science" stack exchange, even though it explicitly has to do with the mathematics of quantum computing.

What criteria is in place for determining when a question from a different site should be moved here? Can we move questions between sites?

Comment: While you shouldn't migrate unless needed, it is acceptable to mention  this site (in the comments) when someone asks a new question about QC on another site. In particular, if the question is related to another question on this site, feel free to mention that the question is related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a question is on-topic on a site, it need not be migrated elsewhere. Since that question is on-topic on Computer Science Stack Exchange, it does not need to be migrated here.

If questions on other sites aren't on topic there but are on topic here, then they can be moved here.

See also:

- [This meta post](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/170/91) on migrating (though it is from our site to elsewhere and is on a specific situation)
- [This mother meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet) on crossover questions between sites